# How to disable sorting in cleveref for one instance?

Tags: cleveref

I can disable reference sorting globally using the `nosort` or the `compress` package options, that's described in the docs. The same chapter explains how to disable compression for one instance of `\cref`. But it doesn't mention how to disable sorting for one instance.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\label{sec:foo}

\subsection{Bar}
\label{sec:foo.bar}

\section{Refs}
Check \cref{sec:foo.bar,sec:foo}

\end{document}
```

Output is "See sections 1 and 1.1", but I would like "See sections 1.1 and 1".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set temporarily to false the conditional `\if@cref@sort`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\crefnosort}[1]{%
  \begingroup\@cref@sortfalse\cref{#1}\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\label{sec:foo}

\subsection{Bar}
\label{sec:foo.bar}

\section{Refs}
Check \crefnosort{sec:foo.bar,sec:foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\DeclareRobustCommand` is a precaution in case the command finds its way in a `\caption`.

Comment: Okay, this works nicely. Except: When I use `\crefnosort` in a caption. So I missed to include that in my MWE. Should I add that to my MWE?

Comment: @Elrond Change `\newcommand` into `\DeclareRobustCommand` or use `\protect\crefnosort` in a caption.

Comment: Would you mind improving your answer?